# Bug: stack overflow on stackoverflow. How ironic

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is this SO offline page all about?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56771/what-is-this-so-offline-page-all-about)

When I visited Stack Overflow a few hours back, I got a message that the site was down for maintenance. Then I saw that there was a Stack Overflow error. Isn't that funny? The message is repeated several times. It is displayed as an image and so I copied it.

The error message reads:

Stack Overflow is currently offline for maintenance
Routine maintenance usually takes less than an hour. You may retry your request or if this turns into an extended outage, we will post details on the blog
10/9/2010 Offline - Stack Overflow
sstatic.net/stackoverflow/app_offline.ht… 1/210/9/2010 Offline - Stack Overflow
sstatic.net/stackoverflow/app_offline.ht… 2/2

stack overflow

R6003
- integer divide by 0

R6009
- not enough space for environment

R6018
- unexpected heap error

run-time error R6002
- floating-point support not loaded

Comment: They were just images. The site was down for other reasons.

Comment: It is a joke, to play on the irony. All it means is the website was down for maintenance.